# Rewrite rule to get rid of sub-directory reference in url

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite **www.xyz.com/pages/login.php** (and all such urls) to: **www.xyz.com/login**

I am using the below rules in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /pages/$1.php [L]
```

With above I am able to get rid of .php extension but not the "/Pages"

Any help please?

Also, any other tips are welcome

Answer (score 0):

To remove the "/pages" use the following rewrite rule:

> RewriteRule ^/(pages)/*      - [L]